# Setting "Callable" on a Java object from within Nashorn script

Tags: java, nashorn, scriptengine

I have a class instance that has a `Callable` field on it. I set this instance on a `Bindings` object. I need to set the `Callable` field from within Nashorn, to be called in Java. How would I set this field from within a Nashorn script?

The script is called like this:

```java
//in java
class Options {
    Callable<Boolean> handler;
}
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
Bindings bindings = engine.createBindings();
Options options = new Options();
bindings.put("options", options);
engine.setBindings(bindings, ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
engine.eval(script);
Invocable executor = (Invocable) engine;
executor.invokeFunction("init");
```

And in the script, I need to set the `handler` field on the global `Options` object:

```
//in nashorn
function init() {
    //How would I set a Callable on this field, from within nashorn?
    options.handler = ?
}
```

I have seen the (suggested duplicate) question [How to use Nashorn engine to call Java Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52399749/how-to-use-nashorn-engine-to-call-java-objects), but that question is about calling a Java method from a Nashorn script, whereas this question is about setting a callable inside a Nashorn script, which can then be called from Java (basically the opposite).

Comment: About your actual question: I don't know the answer (and have no experience with nashorn). It seems you want to call some logic inside the nashorn script from java. Is it not possible to define a normal function in the script and call it the same way as the 'init' function is called?

Comment: Actually, the only thing nashorn needs to do here is set `handler`, which I thought would be as easy as setting a lambda as in java, but it did not work. I actually have no control over how the script is called, and I don't know much of what's going on in java side of things. I have to write a nashorn script that just sets handlers on objects in an `init` function, and that is called elsewhere back in java. All I was given was that `Options` would be set globally, and it would need to have a field `handler` set to a callable.

Comment: Previously, I had set it using prebuilt callables from java-side classes, like `Options.handler = Java.type('com.example.Handlers').SomeCallable`, but now I need to define the callables from within nashorn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the 'Extending classes' section in this [nashorn tutorial](https://winterbe.com/posts/2014/04/05/java8-nashorn-tutorial/). Tested, worked for me:

```
   var Callable = Java.type('java.util.concurrent.Callable');
   var CallableImpl = Java.extend(Callable, {
     call: function() {
       print('test');
     }
   });
   
   options.handler = new CallableImpl();
```

Comment: Pure gold. Thank you for this and that tutorial, I'll be checking it out. Thanks again for helping me fix this question

Comment: Glad to hear, it was fun! First time I managed to get a question reopened, too ;)

Comment: Well it is very much appreciated :)